# mongoose findOne : different between async & sync

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I have confuse with know what is different between :

```
var users = Users.findOne({key})

var users = await Users.findOne({key})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var users = Users.findOne({key})
```

`Users.findOne()` method returns a promise which can either be resolved or rejected. See [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

So in above case users variable actually  contains a `promise` object and  if you want to get the resolved data you have to do something like

```
users.then(data=>{
// your db query data
}).catch(err=>{
// error if something goes wrong
})
```

The below syntax with await actually gives you the resolved data of `promise`  see [await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

```
 var users = await Users.findOne({key})
```

so you will have data like this `[{key:value}]` of your mongodb stored in `users` variable.

Also `await` is valid only in async function so you need to wrap it inside async function

```
async function foo(){
    var users = await Users.findOne({key})

}
```